# Why does setting minWidth to .infinity crash SwiftUI app with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11.4, ios13.4

Here is the exact code that I am running on iOS 13.4/Xcode 11.4:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .frame(minWidth: .infinity)
    }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

The crash happens in iOS, so it's hard to get much useful information other than the following:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
#0  0x00007fff2c7cd371 in NSAttributedString.MetricsCache.findMetrics(requestedSize:) ()
```

Setting `minWidth` to something other than `.infinity` fixes the crash, so my question is why is it crashing and should I report it to Apple?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Setting minWIdth to .infinity means the width must be infinite, which is impossible

Comment: I was trying to make the frame to be at 100%, then hit this issue, I realized the fix was to use `.maxWidth`, but also wanted to get to the bottom of this crash.

Comment: Trying to get the view to take up the whole width of the screen. If setting `minWidth: .infinity` isn't the right way to accomplish this it's a clear violation of the principle of least astonishment, and the fact that it _crashes_ is just embarrassing. Setting `maxWidth: .infinity` doesn't make it do what I want in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.infinity` is an allowed value for a frame's `maxWidth` NOT for its `minWidth` it seems.

Comment: Yeh, wish they had a more easily understood error. Should I report to Apple?

Comment: I doubt that'll change anything, because `.infinity` is a Float, an otherwise valid parameter for frame sizes. I strongly believe it's a parameter assertion that's throwing here.